# How do I transform sensor stream in Flutter to a less-frequent stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, android-sensors, periodic-task

I have created a stream that sends Barometer readings every few milliseconds (non-configurable through the Android Sensors API). Using this stream, I would like to create another stream that only receives the reading every 10 seconds. This is because I only want to compare the readings between 10 second intervals so that any pressure reading difference detected is significant enough for me to process.

Here is my code for the Barometer readings stream:

```
// Starts subscription to barometer events
  static startBarometerService() {
    oldReading = 0;
    newReading = 0;
    upFloor = false;
    downFloor = false;
    subscription = barometerEvents.listen(onBarometer);
    streamController = new StreamController();
    print("[BAROMETER] started listening to barometer events");
  }

  static onBarometer(BarometerEvent event) {
    oldReading = newReading;
    newReading = event.reading;
    updateFloor();
  }
```

I also have another stream created based on the barometer stream to compare altitude and check whether the user has gone up or down a floor, like so:

```
static updateFloor(double reading) {
    if ((newReading - oldReading) > 10) {
      upFloor = true;
      print("[BAROMETER] User went up one floor");
      streamController.add([upFloor, downFloor]);
    } else if ((newReading - oldReading) < -10) {
      downFloor = true;
      streamController.add([upFloor, downFloor]);
      print("[BAROMETER] User went down one floor");
    }
    else {
      upFloor = false;
      downFloor = false;
    }
  }
```

Now, I want my `newReading` and `oldReading` to be sampled 10 seconds apart so that there is a significant enough difference.

Yes I'm aware that the Android Sensors API allows me to input a user-defined sampling rate, but that does not work reliably (in the API docs, they say that it is only taken as a 'hint to the system'). Hence I would like to know how to implement this periodic timer using Dart code.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: see [audit](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/RateLimit/audit.html)

Comment: @pskink thank you! 3 hours of googling and I couldn't find that, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: sure, your welcome, you can also use [throttle](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/RateLimit/throttle.html) - btw if you are using `rx-dart` it has similar methods too

Comment: ok, ok, you already said so ;-) and if you want to reduce the notification frequency even further you can use `Stream.distinct()` method